# 4G LTE is prioritized over LAN/Ethernet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, priority

I have an issue with my laptop and internet connections.
In my system, if there is no WiFi, the system prioritizes cellular broadband instead of ethernet. As soon as I connect WiFi, LAN is prioritized.
I have set priority via metric settings, but to no avail. Also tried the same via Powershell.

Anyone with a solution?

Lenovo X1 Yoga (2nd gen)
Sierra Wireless LTE-modem
Thunderbolt docking station
Windows 10 Pro